# How can I to detect if an Application been created with Winforms or WPF?

Tags: wpf

Without entering the code?

Comment: You could use Reflector.

Comment: @Ronald: That would be 'entering the code'.

Comment: @Henk But since it is impossible to see from the outside how the app is written, you would always have to look inside it. You could of course write something yourself that does this, but using Reflector is easier. And then you get a lot of extras, like source code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use [Snoop](http://blois.us/Snoop/).  If it appears in the list of applications you can "Snoop", that's a WPF app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the DLLs the application loads ([how to do something like that from c#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/dll_profiler.aspx)). WPF classes are in completely different set of assemblies than WinForms classes.

This is not completely reliable though. Application can use both WinForms and WPF at the same time (and load both sets assemblies).